# What's the difference between regular (aka full), position and short papers?

Tags: publications, conference

I've sent the article to the conference and it has been accepted. However, I received a message that my paper has been accepted as the short paper.

I know that there's a difference in, for instance, the oral presentation time between those 3 kinds of papers. However, I wonder if the type (regular, position, short) can say anything about the *quality* or the *importance* of the paper's subject?

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I have observed at the peer-reviewed conferences that I attend:

- A regular full paper is your basic standard peer-reviewed paper.
- A position paper is for ideas that don't have any results, per se, but are worth communicating to the community, or for announcing a result that has been published with another community.
- A short paper is for work that is worth publishing, but doesn't rise to the level of quality or significance of a full paper.

Short papers are generally significantly less respected than full papers, but may be worth it anyway: a short paper in a high-profile conference is often better than a full paper in a less significant conference.  Position papers are funny and in a different category: they aren't attempting to be the same as a full paper, and are typically judged more by a standard of "interesting to discuss."

Answer (score 7):

I will speak from the CS perspective, which I know.

> If the type (regular, position, short) can say anything about the
>   quality or the importance of the paper's subject?

Unfortunately, it does. Although the short paper will still appear in the proceedings, it will have a maximum limit of usually 4 pages. Therefore most details will have to be omitted, due to the limited space. Also, in CS conferences short papers might be presented in a fast-forward fashion (1-2 minutes per paper) or together with the demo papers presentation and therefore they do not attract as much attention as the regular papers. In that case, during the demo / poster session people can come in to your "booth" and discuss about your paper (which is more informal but still a nice way to network).

The better way to take advantage of this situation (your paper was accepted after all, even as a short paper) is to make an extended version of this paper for submitting to a relevant journal, where you can reveal all the missing details from the proceedings short version, along with some additional extra material.

Answer (score 3):

To add to other answers, I'll say that at least in HCI, it depends on the conference. At CHI, for example a short paper is not necessarily one that has less quality. It means that the contribution can be adequately be described and discussed in 4 pages. 
However, there are other conferences who explictly declare in their CfPs that short papers can be about preliminary results, works in progress, etc.

If we are talking about evaluating a researcher's CV, a preponderance of short-papers might indicate that the person in question was not able to focus on any one topic long enough to study it in detail.